# How to display all graph layouts at once?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

I often find myself manually trying different graph layouts (Radial Drawing, Layered Drawing, etc ...) to find the best possible visualization for graphs. Is there a quick command to display ALL graph layouts at once? So that I can pick the best configuration.

Comment: You can write a function that does this once, then keep using it as you need it

Comment: Given how ubiquitous and useful this problem can be, I am asking whether there is a quick way of doing this generation. A Table where I copy paste all the layouts is a possibility, but very likely not the most efficient way.

Comment: maybe something like `embeddings = {"BalloonEmbedding", "CircularEmbedding", 
   "GridEmbedding", "LayeredEmbedding", "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", 
   "RadialEmbedding", "SpectralEmbedding", "SpringEmbedding"};
layoutButtons[g_Graph] := Grid@Partition[
   Button[Panel@ Tooltip[Thumbnail[Rasterize@Graph[EdgeList@g, GraphLayout -> #], Tiny], #], CopyToClipboard[Defer[GraphLayout -> #]], 
      Method -> "Queued"] & /@ embeddings, 4];
layoutButtons[graph]`?

Comment: you can also select from a limited set of choices available under  `GraphLayout`  from the  right-click context menu. (It should be possible to modify this list to add more embeddings and tooltip previews).

Comment: @kglr This is perfect, thanks.  The only thing I changed (is Tiny to Large) in case others want a bigger visualization. The list can also be made larger like you said.

Comment: "I am asking whether there is a quick way of doing this generation" No, there is not. You need to implement it yourself, then you can re-use it as many times as you want without additional effort.

Comment: Well, it turns out this question generated a useful result, beyond your condescending answers. I am familiar with the concept of a function, it wasn't a question that anybody asked but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was provided by kglr (Minor edits from me):

```
embeddings = {"BalloonEmbedding", "CircularEmbedding", 
  "GridEmbedding", "LayeredEmbedding", "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", 
  "RadialEmbedding", "SpectralEmbedding", "SpringEmbedding", 
  "BipartiteEmbedding", "TutteEmbedding", "StarEmbedding", 
  "TutteEmbedding", "SpringElectricalEmbedding", "GravityEmbedding", 
  "MultipartiteEmbedding", "LinearEmbedding", 
  "CircularMultipartiteEmbedding", "DiscreteSpiralEmbedding"}; 
layoutButtons[g_Graph] := 
 Grid@Partition[
   Button[Panel@
       Tooltip[Thumbnail[
         Rasterize@Graph[EdgeList@g, GraphLayout -> #], Large], #], 
      CopyToClipboard[Defer[GraphLayout -> #]], 
      Method -> "Queued"] & /@ embeddings, 4];
```

Function use:

```
layoutButtons[graph]
```

where graph is the object you are trying to visualize.