# Different codes give different star embedding graph layout

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I usually use the following code to generate a star embedding graph layout.

```
Graph[graph, GraphLayout -> "StarEmbedding", EdgeStyle -> Gray, 
 VertexLabels -> None]
```

However, I also use the following code ([based on this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/249994/125)) to view all graph embeddings. I don't why these two codes are giving me different star embeddings? What is the difference?

```
    embeddings = {"BalloonEmbedding", "CircularEmbedding", 
   "GridEmbedding", "LayeredEmbedding", "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", 
   "RadialEmbedding", "SpectralEmbedding", "SpringEmbedding", 
   "BipartiteEmbedding", "TutteEmbedding", "StarEmbedding", 
   "TutteEmbedding", "SpringElectricalEmbedding", "GravityEmbedding", 
   "MultipartiteEmbedding", "LinearEmbedding", 
   "CircularMultipartiteEmbedding", "DiscreteSpiralEmbedding"};
layoutButtons[g_Graph] := 
  Grid@Partition[
    Button[Panel@
        Tooltip[Thumbnail[
          Rasterize@Graph[EdgeList@g, GraphLayout -> #], Large], #], 
       CopyToClipboard[Defer[GraphLayout -> #]], 
       Method -> "Queued"] & /@ embeddings, 4];
layoutButtons[graph]
```

Comment: try replacing  `Graph[EdgeList@g, GraphLayout -> #]` with `Graph[VertexList @#, EdgeList@g, GraphLayout -> #]`?

Comment: Can you provide more details? I just tried running the two on a random graph I generated and they both look basically the same to me. What differences are you referring to? What version of Mathematica are you running? Perhaps include an image?