# Is a list of all graph layouts available?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, options

Is a list of all graph layouts available? 
For example I want to check all the layouts at once for a specific graph so I'll map this over the list. 
 Of course you can just type the list yourself but that I'm interested in getting all the layouts in an easier way.

```
Graph[{e1, e2, ...}, GraphLayout -> #] & /@ layoutList
```

[image]

Comment: Here's a link to a similar discussion: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249731/how-to-display-all-graph-layouts-at-once

Answer (score 17):

```
ResourceFunction["QueryCodeCompletion"]["GraphLayout","KernelSymbol","Graph","InOptionValuePosition"]
```

[image]

Comment: It's good to mention that these strings include explicit quotation marks. The quotes must be removed before these can be used with the `GraphLayout` option.

Answer (score 11):

> @yode's answer is the better choice, but since it missed some options, here is a manual one that works in this particular case.

The question you asked was discussed during a Live CEOing session (I don't remember the episode). From version 10.2 we have [`WolframLanguageData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframLanguageData.html) which in this particular case, **if we assume each option was used in the documentation examples**, we can somehow extract them.

The code is:

```
list1 =
 Cases[Cases[
     WolframLanguageData["GraphLayout", 
      "DocumentationExampleInputs"], {___, "GraphLayout", "\[Rule]", 
       a__} :> ReplaceAll[ToExpression@{a}, Null -> Nothing], 
     Infinity], {a_String, ___} :> a, Infinity] // DeleteDuplicates //
   Sort

(* Out: {"BalloonEmbedding", "BipartiteEmbedding", "CircularEmbedding", 
"CircularMultipartiteEmbedding", "DiscreteSpiralEmbedding", 
"GravityEmbedding", "GridEmbedding", "HighDimensionalEmbedding", 
"LayeredDigraphDrawing", "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", 
"LayeredEmbedding", "LinearEmbedding", "MultipartiteEmbedding", 
"PlanarEmbedding", "RadialEmbedding", "RandomEmbedding", 
"SpectralEmbedding", "SphericalEmbedding", "SpiralEmbedding", 
"SpringElectricalEmbedding", "SpringEmbedding", "StarEmbedding", 
"TutteEmbedding"} *)
```

@yode answer (`\"` was removed from options):

```
yode = StringReplace[
  ResourceFunction["QueryCodeCompletion"]["GraphLayout", 
   "KernelSymbol", "Graph", "InOptionValuePosition"], "\"" -> ""]

(* Out: {"SpringElectricalEmbedding", "SpringEmbedding", 
"HighDimensionalEmbedding", "LayeredEmbedding", 
"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "BalloonEmbedding", "RadialEmbedding", 
"SpiralEmbedding", "BipartiteEmbedding", "CircularEmbedding", 
"CircularMultipartiteEmbedding", "DiscreteSpiralEmbedding", 
"GridEmbedding", "LinearEmbedding", "MultipartiteEmbedding", 
"PlanarEmbedding", "StarEmbedding", "SpectralEmbedding", 
"TutteEmbedding", "GraphLayout", "Graph"} *)
```

#### Comparison

```
(* options exist in yode but not in list1 *)

Complement[yode, list1]

(* Out: {"Graph", "GraphLayout"} *)



(* options exist in list1 but not in yode *)

Complement[list1, yode]

(* Out: {"GravityEmbedding", "LayeredDigraphDrawing", "RandomEmbedding", "SphericalEmbedding"} *)
```

An interesting point is that all the options end with `Embedding` except `"LayeredDigraphDrawing"` (the option used in an example in the `"LayeredDigraphEmbedding"` section).